# Dynamic game - help

Tags: game-theory

Consider  the  following  multistage  game.   Player  1  first  has  to  choose  how  to  divide
$2 between himself and player 2 (with only non-negative integer divisions being possible).
Both players observe the division, and then they play the simultaneous-move game with
the dollar payoffs shown below.

\begin{array}
x & A & B & C\\
U& x,x & 0,0 & -2,-2\\
D&0,0 & 1,1 & -2,-2\\
\end{array}

Assume that each player has utility equal to the sum of the expected number of dollars
he receives in the divide-the-two-dollars game and the expected dollar payoff he receives in
the second-stage game.

(a) Show that for any
x
the game has a Nash equilibrium in which player 1 chooses to
give both dollars to player 2 in the initial divide-the-two-dollars game.
(b) For what values of
x
will the game have a unique subgame-perfect equilibrium?
(c) For what values of
x
is there a subgame-perfect equilibrium in which player 1 gives
both dollars to player 2 in the initial divide-the-two-dollars game?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you explain your table of moves/payoffs please? And questions here, especially of this "exercise" type, are generally better received if you give some indication of your thoughts / progress on the question

Comment: Hi Joffan, the matrix shows the payoffs of player 1 (U, D) and player 2 (A, B, C), given the other player's strategy.
My question about this game is very general, I find it difficult to understand why a payoff of the type (0,2) would ever be a nash equilibrium, if there is no way Player 2 could make a believable threat to player 1.

Comment: What is the range of possible values for $x$?

Comment: $x$ can take any value